# execute mongo commands via shell script

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to my mongo data base and perform some commands on it such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

mongo myMongoDbip:27017/admin -u username -p pwd

mongo --shell --eval  "use neura_staging"
```

i can connect to the data base but all my other commands are not working such as using specific db.

can you elaborate some info about it?

thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the resulting output of your script?

Comment: I am connecting to the database but I notice that the command was not executed... I mean for using the other data base.

Answer (score 2):

You should have something like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash

USER=username
PW=secret
AUTHDB=admin
LOGINDATA="-u $USER -p $PW --authenticationDatabase $AUTHDB"
HOST=hostname.example.com

mongo $HOST:27017 $LOGINDATA --shell --eval ’use neura_staging’
```

The reason why your second call to `mongo` does not work as expected is the this call opens a *new* (and since you did not provide any login data unauthenticated) connection.